# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables named 'users' and 'sponsors' bellow - first one is 'users' and second one is 'sponsors'
[image: users]

[image: sponsors]

I am trying to get the user details from 'users' table where all users from 'sponsors' table used another user 'user_name' as their sponsor. I wrote something like bellow- when trying to join tables then getting this error.What should be the right query? Please someone help me.

```
$a = Sentinel::getUser()->user_name;
                $m = DB::table('sponsors')
                        ->select('user_name')
                        ->where('sponsor', '=', $a)
                        ->get();
                //dd($m);
                $second_downline_members = DB::table('sponsors')
                                            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'sponsors.user_id')
                                            ->where('users.id', $m)
                                            ->get();
                dd($second_downline_members);
```

Comment: $m is collection and you are trying to pass it as string on ->where('users.id', $m)

Comment: Then what should be the right query?

Comment: provided an answer for getting sponsors for user you can try if that help.

Comment: make sure you have some sponsors for the current user and also check the spells for tables and fields.

Comment: already I checked, My current user_name = 'rashed' and others four user_name used 'rashed' as their sponsor. so, I need details for those four 'user_name' details from 'users' table

Comment: you need all users who used rashed as there sponsor right ?

Comment: yes, I want all users details who used rashed as there sponsor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$username = Sentinel::getUser()->user_name;
        $user_ids = \DB::table('sponsors')
            ->where('sponsor', $username)
            ->pluck('user_id');

        $users = \DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $user_ids)->get();

        dd($users);
```

Comment: It's returning nothing items.

Comment: check the value of $a is it id ?

Comment: I just tried my self this is one 100% working fine look into my code 

$id = Auth::user()->id;

```$articles = DB::table('articles')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'articles.user_id')
            ->where('users.id', $id)
            ->get();```

Comment: You are getting all users, but I need to get all users, who used same user_name as their sponsor.

Comment: let me modify it for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155270/discussion-between-moeen-basra-and-md-rashedul-hasan).

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = Sentinel::getUser()->user_name;
                $m = DB::table('sponsors')
                        ->select('user_name')
                        ->where('sponsor', '=', $a)
                        ->first();
                //dd($m);
                $second_downline_members = DB::table('sponsors')
                                            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'sponsors.user_id')
                                            ->where('users.id', $m->id)
                                            ->get();
                dd($second_downline_members);
```

try this

Comment: Now getting this error- 'Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance'. Also tried ->where('users.user_name', $m->user_name), it's saying 'Property [user_name] does not exist on this collection instance'. But 'user_name' is exist on this collection really.

Comment: did you change *get* to *first* in $m query?

Comment: It's giving only first one user details. Many users can use same sponsor, so I need  to get all users details who used same sponsor.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select to

```
->select('user_name', 'id')
```